# Use Mono Runtime instead of Microsoft's on Windows for Monodevelop

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

Even though I set Mono to the default .NET Runtime on Windows, it insists on using Microsoft .NET framework. Can Monodevelop be configured to use the mono runtime as the runtime environment to execute itself? How and where do I configure this setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a configuration option for this. You can try running MonoDevelop on top of Mono by running "mono MonoDevelop.exe" in MonoDevelop's bin directory, but this has not been extensively tested.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly. I have to admit it is my first stab at mono. Actually it starts faster than the Microsoft runtime and the UI looks cleaner. Especially some colors are right and menu separators lock better, which the MS CLR get's wrong. I wonder why though.

Comment: Visual differences are probably because the GTK+ bundled with Mono is a different version than the one bundled with GTK# for .NET.